# Filtering documents out of search results based on field value

Tags: search

An SPD workflow changes a custom column field "Document Status" to the value "Archive" following approval process. Great, because now we have the value to filter out from public view without deleting it along with the history. The problem is still my users can see these in search results. My question is does anyone know a way to filter these out of the results page just based on that property and without affecting global search behavior?

I've looked at using a property filter like described here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792872(v=office.14).aspx but my custom column doesn't show as option to exclude in the list. I don't know if, how, that works and would appreciate any help.

Regards,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need to enable the field in Central Admin to be able to be used as a managed property. http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/customizing-search-series-creating-new-managed-properties-from-bdc-crawled-content.

Once it is configured as a managed property, then you can configure it in scopes and do an exclude where Document Status = Archive.

Comment: Is there a way a Site Owner or a Site Collection Administrator (without access to Central Admin) can do this? The question mentions that this is a custom column, which suggests (to me at least) that it was created below the web app level. I also ask because I'm an SCA without access to Central Admin and want to do this on my site collection too.

Comment: Managed properties can only be created in Central Admin and that is what is used in scopes, so if you are on 2010, then an IT guy is going to have to create the managed property. If on 2013, then I'm not certain.